# Why are Hogwarts Quiddich players allowed to have an unfair advantage in brooms?

Tags: harry-potter

I would expect all players to have the same make of broom. Draco's bribe to get into the Slytherin team shouldn't be possible. Harry's broom should be the same as the others'.

Why was this allowed at school?

Comment: @JasonBaker, even if skill trumps equipment, it will cause discord - a losing team can still disparge the winning team's skill. A school allowing this should allow a wealthy student to assault poorer students, its only consistent.

Comment: The wizarding world seems full of contradictions.

Comment: @Valorum Although I don't think this one of them... in the real world when schools and student-athletes have to buy their own equipment, the wealthier will have the best.

Comment: @Skooba - Yes, but a lot of the stuff they're allowed to bring (at least in the first year) seems quite heavily standardised